# Const in function on constrained devices

Tags: c, embedded

I just have a short question about memory management in C on constrained devices.
Generally speaking: global const variables end up in the flash of the microcontroller.
Variables locally defined end up on the stack, therefore in the memory.
But how about const variables defined in functions? They just end up in the stack, right, since they only locally available within the function and need to be cleared after executing the function. Or do they end up in the flash?

Comment: Review the map file generated by the linker after the build to learn the location of the variables in question.  If it's not in the map file then review the generated assembly to see how the assembly retrieves the value.  I doubt that local variables "need to be cleared after executing the function".  "Local" specifies the scope of access to the variable, not necessarily the lifetime of the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer:* Many but not necessarily all embedded compiler systems work in a similar way. I'm trying to condense my 30+ years of working with embedded systems in some simplified statements. Don't take them for granted for *any* embedded system.

---

> global const variables end up in the flash of the microcontroller.

Global variables are static variable. Static constant variables are commonly placed in a section for read-only initialized data. This is not necessarily the same section as the executable code, but it might be.

However, the linker combines such (logical) sections into (physical) sections. If the target uses flash memory for this, then global constant variables will be in flash.

Some linkers treat these data sections differently, and place them in RAM. The `const` qualifier might be used for a memory management unit that write-protects the RAM region. Anyway, the compiler checks that you don't write into such variables, as far as it can do this.

> Variables locally defined end up on the stack, therefore in the memory.

This depends heavily on the system and the variable's qualifiers.

- Optimization might place local variables in registers.
- Optimization might not assign a location to a constant at all and use the value directly.
- You can use `static` on local variables. Then this variable is only visible from inside the block it is defined in, and its inner blocks. But its placement is commonly the same as for global variables. It will keep its value during all of the run-time.
- You can use both `const` and `static` on local variables. This will usually place this variable in the same section as the global constant variables.
- Really constrainted systems like 8051 use the stack for local variables only when asked for, in example if recursion is needed. Most commonly compiler and linker analyze the lifetimes and place local variables statically in a common section. The very same memory location will be used for different local variables with non-overlapping lifetimes.

> But how about const variables defined in functions? They just end up in the stack, [...] Or do they end up in the flash?

Conclusion 1: Add the correct qualifier, and most probably it will be placed where you  want it.

Conclusion 2: You need to read the documentation of *your* system. And you need to make some experiments, examining the linker's map files.

---

Note 1: Many systems have one way or another to control the placement further. For example, with GCC you can use `__attribute__((section("any-section-you-like")))` to assign objects to another section. Linker scripts are also some way.

Note 2: The majority of embedded systems I worked with don't "load" programs. The executable code will be run in-place. In an equal manner static constant variables will not be loaded, but read from the memory they are stored in non-volatile memory.

Answer (score 0):

Primarily memory model in C looks something like following:

[image]

The five segments are defined as:

- Code Segment - Stores `code` part, ROM
- Data segment - Stores **initialised** `global` and `static` variables
- Stack segment - Stores local variables, function arguments, return address. This is further segmented as `frames of stacks`.
- Heap segment - Dynamic allocations happens here like `malloc`.
- BSS (or Block Started by Symbol) segment - Stores uninitialised `global` and `static` variables

`const` keyword is **qualifier** to the compiler, that it must be stored in write protected region of memory segment, now compiler has to decide where it has to go:

if it is `unitialised -> bss` else `initialised -> data segment`

In microcontrollers ([memory model](https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v6.2/apis/memory-model.html)) ROM memory is on FLASH, for microcontroller memory details [here](https://os.mbed.com/handbook/Memory-Model#:%7E:text=not%20directly%20addressable.-,C%20Memory%20Model,RAM%20available%20on%20the%20microcontroller.).

Answer (score -1):

"global const variables end up in the flash of the microcontroller"
No, [not necessarily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712167/c-store-global-variables-in-flash).

"const variables defined in functions"
They end up [on the stack](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/204500/when-and-for-what-purposes-should-the-const-keyword-be-used-in-c-for-variables).

A part of the flash is for the instruction code (by your IDE/flashing tool) or otherwise needs to be used explicitly.
(since flash has limited write-cycles)

Comment: The first stackoverflow topic you are referring to is not mentioning global const variables at all. I just know global const variables are in the flash. Not talking about normal global variables. Talking specifically about const variables.

Comment: Yes, I know and const variables are read-only, this is why I am asking. I don't get the impression you understand my question tbh. And flash is not only for instruction code. It also hold initialization data which will get copied into the RAM. Just an example.

Comment: @Citrullin https://stackoverflow.com/a/6395033/9306292 "The implementation may place a const object that is not volatile in a read-only region of storage."

Comment: I did not write about all stuff that goes into flash, since that was not asked.

Comment: FWIW, const variables defined in probably end up as immediates loaded into registers, not on the stack or in globals.  These immediates may either be directly encoded into the instructions (if they fit the bits provided) or stored in .RODATA or .TEXT (depending on the architecture and compiler)